# I am making nav bar but I don't find the error in making responsive to this nav bar. Can anyone help me

Tags: javascript, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    header{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        background-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
    header a img{
        width: 100px;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
    header #menu-bar {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    header ul li{
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
    }
    header ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0 10px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing:1.4px;
        
    }
    .nav-bar{
        border: 2px solid white;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 10px;
        display:none;
    }
    .fa-bars{
        color: white;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
     .active{
        display: block;
        background:red
    } 

    @media only screen and (max-width:600px){
        header ul {
            display:none;
            margin-top: 200px;
            width: 100vw;
            text-align: center;
            background:skyblue;
            
        }
        .nav-bar{
            display:block;
        }
        header ul li{
            flex-direction: column; 
        }
        header ul li a{
            color: black;
            padding-top: 10px;

        }
        .navbar {
            display: none;
        }
    }

```
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Adding Navbar -->

    <header>
        <a href="#logo" class="logo">
            <img src="./img/Logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
        <ul id="menu-bar">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="" class="nav-bar" id="navBtn"><i class=" fas fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    </header>

     <script>            
      let mainNav = document.getElementById('menu-bar');
        let navBarToggle = document.getElementById('navBtn');

       <!--I am facing a problem in this line-->

        navBarToggle.addEventListener('click', function (){
            mainNav.classList.add('active');
        });
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Format the code a little bit better please

Comment: Change your `<a href="" class="nav-bar" id="navBtn">` to `span`.

Answer (score 0):

Please view the snippet. Everything seems to be running as it should be. Your `navbar` turns into `hamburger-menu` just as instructed to do so in your `media-queries` set at a `max-width: 600px`

For snippet viewing purposes I changed your `media max-width` to `1000px`

```js
let mainNav = document.getElementById('menu-bar');
        let navBarToggle = document.getElementById('navBtn');

       // I am facing a problem in this line 

        navBarToggle.addEventListener('click', function (){
            mainNav.classList.add('active');
        });
```

```css
*{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 header{
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 80px;
     background-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
}
 header a img{
     width: 100px;
     padding-top: 20px;
}
 header #menu-bar {
     list-style-type: none;
}
 header ul li{
     display: flex;
     list-style: none;
}
 header ul li a{
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 0 10px;
     color: white;
     font-size: 18px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing:1.4px;
}
 .nav-bar{
     border: 2px solid white;
     text-align: center;
     margin-right: 10px;
     display:none;
}
 .fa-bars{
     color: white;
     font-size: 18px;
     padding: 5px;
}
 .active{
     display: block;
     background:red 
}
 @media only screen and (max-width:1000px){
     header ul {
         display:none;
         margin-top: 200px;
         width: 100vw;
         text-align: center;
         background:skyblue;
    }
     .nav-bar{
         display:block;
    }
     header ul li{
         flex-direction: column;
    }
     header ul li a{
         color: black;
         padding-top: 10px;
    }
     .navbar {
         display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Adding Navbar -->

    <header>
        <a href="#logo" class="logo">
            <img src="./img/Logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
        <ul id="menu-bar">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="" class="nav-bar" id="navBtn"><i class=" fas fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```