# Mobile navbar menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

im learning hmtl/css and need a menu for my navbar (mobile version ). I watched some java script videos and tried to do same but sadly it dosent work. The menu dosent get hide nothing work tbh. I will be glad if u can advive me or show me a simple way to make one ( my js knowledge is basic ).
Thanks in advance^^

```js
const mobileBtn = document.getElementById("nav-menu");
nav = document.querySelector("nav");
mobileBtnExit = document.getElementById("nav-exit");

mobileBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nav.classList.add("menu-btn");
});

mobileBtnExit.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nav.classList.remove("menu-btn");
});
```

```css
/*
=============== 
NAVBAR
===============
*/
.navbar {
  background: var(--white);
  padding: 10px;
}
.logo {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: var(--black);
}
.logo span {
  color: var(--primary-500);
}
.title {
  display: flex;
  place-content: space-between;
}
#nav-menu {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 66%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: var(--primary-600);
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1em;
}
nav.menu-btn {
  display: block;
}
.home {
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}
nav a {
  color: var(--white);
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: right;
}
nav a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#nav-exit {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<!-- START Navbar -->
    <section class="navbar">
      <div class="title">
        <a class="logo" href="#">Swilam<span>DE</span></a>
        <span><i id="nav-menu" class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <i id="nav-exit" class="fas fa-times"></i>
        <div class="home">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a class="premium" href="#">Go Premium</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </section>
    <!-- End Navbar -->
```

Comment: This questions has [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70024374/i-am-making-nav-bar-but-i-dont-find-the-error-in-making-responsive-to-this-nav/70024789#70024789)

Answer (score -1):

you can use media query

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){

the style here how do you want to be a mobile menu?

}
```

[here you can check details](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav)

Comment: please read the question. OP want's hamburger style menu (mobile menu) to appear when resizing the screen. YES, it will need media queries but your answer does not relate to the nature of the question.

Comment: a working on the mobile version first, i dont need media query yet the navbar dosent work at all